# Visualize the number of NAs in each column using ggplot2 heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this vector that holds the amount of NAs in each column of a dataset.

```
countNA <-  c(0, 0, 88, 88, 161, 84, 540, 0, 84, 84, 84, 86, 101, 77, 80, 80, 72, 119, 72, 0, 72, 86, 72, 70, 70, 70, 161, 86, 80, 101, 77, 497, 80, 161, 88, 84, 86, 497, 471, 81, 560, 88, 88, 497, 472, 84, 0)
```

And i would like to plot it as a heatmap in ggplot2

```
countNA <-  c(0, 0, 88, 88, 161, 84, 540, 0, 84, 84, 84, 86, 101, 77, 80, 80, 72, 119, 72, 0, 72, 86, 72, 70, 70, 70, 161, 86, 80, 101, 77, 497, 80, 161, 88, 84, 86, 497, 471, 81, 560, 88, 88, 497, 472, 84, 0)
plotNA3 <- as.data.frame(countNA, row.names = NULL)
plotNA3$VariableNames <- as.factor(seq(1, length(countNA)))
plotNA3$team <- as.factor(rep(1, length(countNA)))

ggplot(data = plotNA3, aes(x=VariableNames, y=team, fill=countNA)) +
  geom_tile() +
  labs(fill='Number of NAs in each column')+
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(sprintf("%.1d", countNA))), size=2, color="white")
```

However, as you will see if you run this, it is not a piece of square tiles but is stretched. Is it possible to change it a bit so that the y axis is not streched?

I am guessing the true question is "How to create a heatmap that has only 1 variable"

Comment: helps this `geom_tile(height=0.1)`?

Comment: This option just scales the tiles inside the main layer. I would like all the plot to be "scaled" but i cannot find how

Comment: Take a look at the [`visdat`](https://github.com/ropensci/visdat) package. It has function designed to easily explore missing data for each column in a dataset, and it is built on top of ggplot

Comment: Ok, then this? `theme(legend.position="top",
        ,plot.margin = margin(0, 1, 1, 1, "cm"))`

Comment: cannot see any real difference, but i ll toy a bit with the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
ggplot(data = plotNA3, aes(x=VariableNames, y=team, fill=countNA)) +
  geom_tile() +
  labs(fill='Number of NAs in each column')+
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(sprintf("%.1d", countNA))), size=2, color="white")+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1/25)
```

[image]